# NMock2.0 - how to stub a non interface call?

Tags: tdd, mocking, typemock, nmock

I have a class API which has full code coverage and uses DI to mock out all the logic in the main class function (Job.Run) which does all the work.

I found a bug in production where we werent doing some validation on one of the data input fields.

So, I added a stub function called ValidateFoo()... Wrote a unit test against this function to Expect a JobFailedException, ran the test - it failed obviously because that function was empty. I added the validation logic, and now the test passes.

Great, now we know the validation works. Problem is - how do I write the test to make sure that ValidateFoo() is actually called inside Job.Run()? ValidateFoo() is a private method of the Job class - so it's not an interface...

Is there anyway to do this with NMock2.0? I know TypeMock supports fakes of non interface types. But changing mock libs right now is not an option. At this point if NMock can't support it, I will simply just add the ValidateFoo() call to the Run() method and test things manually - which obviously I'd prefer not to do considering my Job.Run() method has 100% coverage right now. Any Advice? Thanks very much it is appreciated.

***EDIT: the other option I have in mind is to just create an integration test for my Job.Run functionality (injecting to it true implementations of the composite objects instead of mocks). I will give it a bad input value for that field and then validate that the job failed. This works and covers my test - but it's not really a unit test but instead an integration test that tests one unit of functionality.... hmm..***

EDIT2: IS there any way to do tihs? Anyone have ideas? Maybe TypeMock - or a better design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The current version of NMock2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nmock2/) can mock concrete types (I don't remember exactly which version they added this, but we're using version 2.1) using the mostly familiar syntax:

```
Job job = mockery.NewMock<Job>(MockStyle.Transparent);
Stub.On(job).Method("ValidateFoo").Will(Return.Value(true));
```

MockStyle.Transparent specifies that anything you don't stub or expect should be handled by the underlying implementation - so you can stub and set expectations for methods on an instance you're testing.

However, you can only stub and set expectations on public methods (and properties), which must also be virtual or abstract. So to avoid relying on integration testing, you have two options:

- Make `Job.ValidateFoo()` public and virtual.
- Extract the validation logic into a new class and inject an instance into `Job`.

Answer (score 1):

Since all private are all called by public methods (unless relying on reflection runtime execution), then those privates are being executed by public methods. Those private methods are causing changes to the object beyond simply executing code, such as setting class fields or calling into other objects. I'd find a way to get at those "results" of calling the private method. (Or mocking the things that shouldn't be executed in the private methods.)

I can't see the class under test.  Another problem that could be pushing you to want access to the private methods is that it's a super big class with a boatload of private functionality. These classes may need to be broken down into smaller classes, and some of those privates may turn into simpler publics.